# H3 Hexagon Geometry join on MSA Geometry

Tags: geojson, geopandas, spatial-join, h3, dggs

I have a pandas DataFrame with `h3` hex ids and corresponding `Polygon` geometries and a `geojson` file with Texas Metro Area Geometries.

I'd like to join the H3 hex ID to Metro area and identify which Metro Areas, the hexIDs belong to.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
"hex_id": [816383, 816384, 816385, 816386, 816387],
"geometry": [
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(-95.521062, 29.729679), (-95.521062, 29.746879), (-95.504662, 29.746879), (-95.504662, 29.729679), (-95.521062, 29.729679)]]},
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(-95.504662, 29.729679), (-95.504662, 29.746879), (-95.488262, 29.746879), (-95.488262, 29.729679), (-95.504662, 29.729679)]]},
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(-95.488262, 29.729679), (-95.488262, 29.746879), (-95.471862, 29.746879), (-95.471862, 29.729679), (-95.488262, 29.729679)]]},
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(-95.471862, 29.729679), (-95.471862, 29.746879), (-95.455462, 29.746879), (-95.455462, 29.729679), (-95.471862, 29.729679)]]},
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(-95.455462, 29.729679), (-95.455462, 29.746879), (-95.439062, 29.746879), (-95.439062, 29.729679), (-95.455462, 29.729679)]]}
]
})
```

`GeoJson`:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-95.677246, 29.712342],
            [-95.677246, 30.298214],
            [-94.634033, 30.298214],
            [-94.634033, 29.712342],
            [-95.677246, 29.712342]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Dallas-Fort Worth Metroplex"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-95.997681, 29.712342],
            [-95.997681, 30.035241],
            [-95.677246, 30.035241],
            [-95.677246, 29.712342],
            [-95.997681, 29.712342]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Austin Metroplex"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-95.390793, 29.009628],
            [-95.390793, 29.712342],
            [-94.634033, 29.712342],
            [-94.634033, 29.009628],
            [-95.390793, 29.009628]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Houston Metroplex"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-96.898499, 27.706915],
            [-96.898499, 29.009628],
            [-95.390793, 29.009628],
            [-95.390793, 27.706915],
            [-96.898499, 27.706915]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "San Antonio Metroplex"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I join the pandas DataFrame to `GeoJson` geometries and identify which metro Area the HexID belongs to? Expected output is to add a new column with `name` of the metro Area.

Comment: You need to use [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/index.html) instead of pandas and use [Spatial Join](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/spatial_joins.html#Spatial-Joins).

Comment: If you have many more H3 cells to work with, it might be better to polyfill your metro areas, and then to perform an attribute join on H3 cell IDs. That's really the whole idea of using a DGGS like H3, to avoid spatial operations.

Answer (score 0):

Create two GeoDataFrames from your data and [Spatial Join](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/spatial_joins.html) the grid to the metros. Your five grid cells are all in Dallas-Fort Worth.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import shape
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

grid = pd.DataFrame({
"hex_id": [816383, 816384, 816385, 816386, 816387],
"geometry": [
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(-95.521062, 29.729679), (-95.521062, 29.746879), (-95.504662, 29.746879), (-95.504662, 29.729679), (-95.521062, 29.729679)]]},
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(-95.504662, 29.729679), (-95.504662, 29.746879), (-95.488262, 29.746879), (-95.488262, 29.729679), (-95.504662, 29.729679)]]},
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(-95.488262, 29.729679), (-95.488262, 29.746879), (-95.471862, 29.746879), (-95.471862, 29.729679), (-95.488262, 29.729679)]]},
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(-95.471862, 29.729679), (-95.471862, 29.746879), (-95.455462, 29.746879), (-95.455462, 29.729679), (-95.471862, 29.729679)]]},
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(-95.455462, 29.729679), (-95.455462, 29.746879), (-95.439062, 29.746879), (-95.439062, 29.729679), (-95.455462, 29.729679)]]}
]})

grid["geometry"] = grid.apply(lambda x: shape(x["geometry"]), axis=1) #create shapely geometries
grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=grid, geometry=grid["geometry"], crs="epsg:4326")

metro = {'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
   'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': [[[-95.677246, 29.712342],
      [-95.677246, 30.298214],
      [-94.634033, 30.298214],
      [-94.634033, 29.712342],
      [-95.677246, 29.712342]]]},
   'properties': {'name': 'Dallas-Fort Worth Metroplex'}},
  {'type': 'Feature',
   'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': [[[-95.997681, 29.712342],
      [-95.997681, 30.035241],
      [-95.677246, 30.035241],
      [-95.677246, 29.712342],
      [-95.997681, 29.712342]]]},
   'properties': {'name': 'Austin Metroplex'}},
  {'type': 'Feature',
   'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': [[[-95.390793, 29.009628],
      [-95.390793, 29.712342],
      [-94.634033, 29.712342],
      [-94.634033, 29.009628],
      [-95.390793, 29.009628]]]},
   'properties': {'name': 'Houston Metroplex'}},
  {'type': 'Feature',
   'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': [[[-96.898499, 27.706915],
      [-96.898499, 29.009628],
      [-95.390793, 29.009628],
      [-95.390793, 27.706915],
      [-96.898499, 27.706915]]]},
   'properties': {'name': 'San Antonio Metroplex'}}]}

metro = gpd.GeoDataFrame().from_features(features=metro, crs="epsg:4326")


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
metro.plot(ax=ax, column="name", legend=True)
grid.plot(ax=ax, color="yellow", edgecolor="black")
```

[image]

```
metro_join_grid = gpd.sjoin(left_df=metro, right_df=grid, how="left", predicate="intersects")

# print(metro_join_grid[["name", "hex_id"]])
#                           name    hex_id
# 0  Dallas-Fort Worth Metroplex  816383.0
# 0  Dallas-Fort Worth Metroplex  816384.0
# 0  Dallas-Fort Worth Metroplex  816385.0
# 0  Dallas-Fort Worth Metroplex  816386.0
# 0  Dallas-Fort Worth Metroplex  816387.0
# 1             Austin Metroplex       NaN
# 2            Houston Metroplex       NaN
# 3        San Antonio Metroplex       NaN
```